# Running a webview from a service

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, leaflet

The below is part of PushListenerService - where android listens for GCM messages being received. I am attempting to implement a javascript function (fireRadius) through webview. The webview is already created through the Main Activity. The intention is to have the JS function update the webview without reloading it.

I suspect either one of two things are amiss:

1. the View is incorrect setup
2. onPageFinished is unnecessary as the webview is already running in the Main Activity. This method fires the JS function if placed in the Main Activity.

This does not result in any errors. The JS function does not run at all.

```
    import android.app.ActivityManager;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    import com.amazon.mysampleapp.R;
    import com.amazonaws.mobile.MainActivity;
    import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    import static com.amazonaws.mobile.util.ThreadUtils.runOnUiThread;


    /**
     * A service that listens to GCM notifications.
     */
    public class PushListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

        private static final String LOG_TAG = PushListenerService.class.getSimpleName();

        // Intent action used in local broadcast
        public static final String ACTION_SNS_NOTIFICATION = "sns-notification";
        // Intent keys
        public static final String INTENT_SNS_NOTIFICATION_FROM = "from";
        public static final String INTENT_SNS_NOTIFICATION_DATA = "data";

        /**
         * Called when message is received.
         *
         * @param from SenderID of the sender.
         * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs. For Set of keys use
         * data.keySet().
         */
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(final String from, final Bundle data) {
            String message = getMessage(data);
            //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "From: " + from);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Message: " + message);

            //TODO create a popup where the user is

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);

                    final WebView webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);

                    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
                webview.setEnabled(true);
                webview.setClickable(true);

                    Log.d("DID IT WORK?", "YEP!!");
                    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/MyMap.html");

                    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                            webview.loadUrl("javascript:fireRadius(" +
                                    43.0000000 + "," +
                                    -79.4000000 + "," +
                                    300 + ",\"" +
                                    "A CIRCLE!" + "\")");
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

            // Display a notification in the notification center if the app is in the background.
            // Otherwise, send a local broadcast to the app and let the app handle it.
            if (isForeground(this)) {
                // broadcast notification
                broadcast(from, data);
            } else {
                displayNotification(text);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Excuse me, maybe you're missing `webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` too (together with JS - this you've already done).

Comment: No, I have included all the below to little use. webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
                webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
                webview.setEnabled(true);
                webview.setClickable(true);

Comment: **setDom** and **SetJS** use to have to be both declared at the same time. If just one of them are used JS doesn't work. Nice you did. Bad it didn't solve your matters. Best luck. (note that now you have declared setJs twice :P.... Not one JS works? Nor even an alert? Or the problem is with your function?

Comment: I've included a console.log() in the JS function: this does not work. However, there is no error for in Java either with onPageFinished. It's as if it skips over it completely

Comment: Yeah, sometimes when a script face a problem, it simply hangs execution or just "forget all" and don't run at the same time don't raise none error, just let the page continues. I don't know if it is valid, but try to simulate your needs on a regular webbrowser, on your desktop pc, it's console can point some precious details...